# jsPDF html does retain CSS, but not the transform rule

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf

Please look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Test File</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myHTML">
        <div id="zTexte" style="ont-size:16px; margin-top: 18px;">Roland Garros</div>    
        <img id="leCourt2" src="IMAGES/iconesTerrain/courtQuick.png"  style="width: 560px;  top:57px; left: 6px; margin: auto" alt="none">
        <img src='IMAGES/iconesTerrain/EleveG.png' style= 'top: 211px; width: 33; height: 33px; left: 94px; position: absolute;' alt="none">
        <img src='IMAGES/iconesTerrain/banc.png' style= 'top: 123px; width:32px; height: 23px; left: 191px; position: absolute; transform: rotate(-90deg);' alt="none">
    </div>

    <script src="../JS/jspdf.debug.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/html2canvas.1.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>        
        var myPDF = new jsPDF ({
                            orientation: 'landscape',
                            unit: 'px', 
                            format: 'a4',
                            compress: 'true'// inefficient
                         }),
            source = document.getElementById('myHTML');

        myPDF.html( source, { callback: myPDF => { myPDF.output('datauri'); } });
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It efficiently converts the HTML elements, *but not the last one*, because it sports `transform: rotate(-90deg)`: no display!

Leaving out this CSS rule will cause the element to be displayed.

What is the matter here? How do I retain the effect of the rotation rule?